# How to set IsModified to false on a navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have `Article` and `ApplicationUser` model classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...

}

public class Article
{
    ...

    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to set CreatedBy property to false this way:

```
base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
```

But I get this error:

> The property 'CreatedBy' on entity type 'ApplicationUser' is being accessed using the 'Property' method, but is defined in the model as a navigation property. Use either the 'Reference' or 'Collection' method to access navigation properties.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `base.Entry(entity).CreatedBy.IsModified = false;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly , the Article entity may looks like :

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    // ...

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

As the error info described , the `CreatedBy` is a navigation property here .

So change your code to

`Entry(entity).Reference(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;` ,

It may work as expected .

Answer (score 1):

I changed to access the `CreatedBy` using the 'Reference' method insted of 'Property' method:

```
base.Entry(entity).Reference(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
```

Comment: If you did exactly as suggested by @itminus then you should accept their answer.